# Login into my website with Facebook account

Tags: email, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I am trying to incorporate the `facebook login button` into my website's homepage. I have connected it with an app, so i have the `app id` and `secret`,  if the user is already registered.

I have used the `JavaScript SDK` from facebook but when I press the facebook's login button, after the authorization, nothing happens and my website's homepage is shown again. Does anyone know how to get the `user's email` from the Javascript SDK? I want to redirect to another page after login, but after login it stays on that page only.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
 <script>

   window.fbAsyncInit = function() 
   {

       FB.init({
          appId      : '178124332351909', // App ID
          channelUrl : 'channel.html', // Channel File
          status     : true, // check login status
          cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
          xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
       });

       FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) 
       {
           if (response.status === 'connected') 
           {
               alert("connected");
               testAPI();
           } 
           else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') 
           {
               alert("nt connected");
               FB.login();
           } 
           else 
           {
               alert("else");
               FB.login();
           }
      });
    };

     // Load the SDK asynchronously
     (function(d){
      var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
      js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
      ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
     }(document));

     // Here we run a very simple test of the Graph API after login is successful. 
     // This testAPI() function is only called in those cases. 
     function testAPI() 
     {
        alert("in testapi");
        console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
        FB.api('/me', function(response) 
        {
            console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
        });
     }

 </script>
```

Reference : [Add the login code](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/getting-started-web/)

Please help how to redirect to another page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. For asking the permission for `email`, replace `Fb.login()`with:

   ```
   FB.login(function(response)
   {
       if(response.status == 'connected'){
           alert('I am connected')
       }
   },{scope: 'email'});
   ```
2. For redirecting the user to other page after successful login, simply write the redirection code in the `testAPI()` function:

   ```
   function testAPI()
   {
       alert("in testapi");
       console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
       FB.api('/me', function(response) 
       {
          console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
       });
       window.location="http://www.newlocation.com";  // HERE
   }
   ```

Comment: for redirecting i wrote the code same like u...but after logi when i click back button it is not going to back...

Comment: You mean the redirection is successful? And why you want to go back? Is it because you are automatically redirected when you open the application? If yes, then you can make a facebook [logout](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.logout/) button, OR you can run you application in `ingonito` browser OR `clear the cache` of browser and run.

Comment: okay...actually the thing is i created the app using my fb login...when i click login in mysite..it asking for mail id and pwd...if it is mine id then its showing my profile name...else it is not showing any one names...why its happening i dont understand...

Comment: Are you saying that only "you" are able to login? If so, then go to your app settings and switch the `Sandbox Mode` to `off`. (You go to your App dashboard from [here](https://developers.facebook.com/apps))

Comment: Wherever you want to. In your new page(for eg), add the SDK and call `FB.init` as you did above and call your method just like you called `FB.Event`

Comment: You can see in my code above i wrote in testApi function where i called FB.api("/me"),by using this i can get the name of the user...for getting email what should i write...???

Comment: As I said you can write your desired API call to any function or anywhere you wish to. I depends on you, where you want to use what.

Comment: `FB.api("/me?fields=email")`. You'll get the object in result as: `{"email": EMAIL, "id":  FB_ID}`

Comment: i wrote like this but it saying undefined... FB.api("/me?fields=email", function(response) {
      console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.fileds + '.');
      //console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.mail + '.');
     // window.location.href='Upload.html';
    },{scope: 'email'});

Comment: `fileds` is not an output, see my comment carefully, `email` is part of object; so write `console.log(response)` - to see the complete object ; or `console.log(response.email)`- to check the email

Answer (score 0):

There could be 1 reason:

- when you click on the login button>> it tries to open the pop- up window>> if "allow pop up is blocked">> then it will just refresh the page, and user will think that nothing is happening.

If you want to get users email then you can pass it as a "perms" parameter something like this.

```
<div class="fb-login-button" onclick="fbLoginClick();" perms="email"><div>
```